# getting a FileNotFoundException using the following code

Tags: android

I am trying to create a logfile of RSSI values and RSSI values once a filter has been applied.  I do not want to use the android logfile.  I want to use  a text file that I can export to excel. This is the code that I have written.  I am new to android, but have some java experience.

```
        state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "MEDIA_MOUNTED is true");
            File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
            File file = new File(path, "RSSI.txt");
            try {
                pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file), true);
                pw.print(beacon.getRssi());
                pw.print(kalman.kalman(rssis));
                pw.println();
                pw.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace of the thrown exception to your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can try creating a new file if it doesn't exist

```
if(!file.exists())
{  
   file.createNewFile()
   // you can start writing to file from here.
}
```

make sure to add permission to read and write from the external storage in the manifest file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much...just could not see that after looking at the code for a while!

Comment: make sure to accept this as the correct answer if this helped.

Comment: Adding createNewFile is a pretty bad idea because needed for nothing.